# Machine Authorization For .NET Application

Tags: .net, authorization

I'm looking at some application requirements for a .NET application which specifies the application must only run on authorized machines and authorized users. This is an internal business application so it's not exactly a licensing matter, but perhaps that could still be a valid approach. Rather than re-invent the wheel, I thought I'd ask what's already available for this sort of thing. As far as authorized users go, I figure the application can manage that during startup, yes?

Comment: You elaborate? What sort of authorization do you want done? What infrastructure do you have available?

Comment: This is taken care of by IT staff using existing infrastructure.  User account, group membership, domain controller.  Programs have no business implementing their own authorization, it isn't secure.

Comment: @hanspassant I disagree; it can indeed be secure. You could write something secure and have it as a lib that all projects use. I've done crypto successfully in many projects myself (password hashing, certificate-chain signing w/ intermediates, OAuth, authorization rules etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep certain details about a computer(eg. MAC and CPU Make and Model, along with the make of mother board) in a file distributed with the application. You could sign the file with RSA to protect it from tampering, you would only distribute the public key with the application.

Assuming you use active directory, to ensure that user names are unique (to prevent people creating an account with the same name on their computer and logging in as it circumventing the user check), you could store a list of authorized user names and again sign with RSA.

When the application starts first check the RSA signatures of the files to check their integrity. Then first check the machine is authorized. Then check the user is authorized. You should check at 2 or more points in the code independently to prevent tampering with the validation in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions based on limited information:

- Use Kerberos in an AD-environment with AD-STS + WIF/Claims to assert on start
- Use an STS+WIF/Claims without AD
- Keep a database of users and their permissions and check that on start-up through an authorization service